# Diagonal Matrix of a Piecewise Function

Tags: functions, matrix, piecewise

I have a piecewise function now I want to do a Matrix operation on it. How can I do that?
For example, the Function is like below:

```
F[s_] := Piecewise[{{s^3, s <= 5}, {s^2, s > 5}}]; 
ds =   0.04 ;
n =  5 ;
s = Table[-2 + ds i, {i, 5} ];
DiagonalMatrix[F[s]]
```

Do I need to define the function in a different way?

Comment: use `DiagonalMatrix[F /@ s]`

Comment: @kglr Thank you very much!

Comment: Or add `Attributes[F] = Listable`.

Comment: @corey979...Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Map` `F` on `s`:

```
DiagonalMatrix[F /@ s] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  -7.52954 & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. \\
>  0. & -7.07789 & 0. & 0. & 0. \\
>  0. & 0. & -6.64467 & 0. & 0. \\
>  0. & 0. & 0. & -6.2295 & 0. \\
>  0. & 0. & 0. & 0. & -5.832 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Or give the function `F` the `Attribute` `Listable` and use `F@s`:

```
ClearAll[F]
F[s_] := Piecewise[{{s^3, s <= 5}, {s^2, s > 5}}];
SetAttributes[F, Listable]
DiagonalMatrix[F @ s] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  -7.52954 & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. \\
>  0. & -7.07789 & 0. & 0. & 0. \\
>  0. & 0. & -6.64467 & 0. & 0. \\
>  0. & 0. & 0. & -6.2295 & 0. \\
>  0. & 0. & 0. & 0. & -5.832 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$